# Is it a valid practice to put javascript inside a partial?

Tags: javascript, ajax, single-page-application

In our current design, we have several partials paired with scripts that act as client-side controllers. These partials are loaded via ajax.

Example:

**employee.jsp**

```
<div id="employee">
  <input type="text" name="fullname" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="employee-submit" data-bind="click : submit"/>
</div>
<script src="employee.js"></script>
```

The biggest issue I've seen with this practice is that it keeps caching the scripts. If caching is not an issue, why should I stay away from this practice? Are there other web developers doing this?

Comment: i tend to have a mast js then only load in from there what i need/require for that page, the problem mostly with this is if you tend to have loads of partials is keeping track of where the individual scripts are loaded form etc

Comment: well the core philosophy we are trying to follow is for every partial we have, we also have a corresponding js controller, hence that `employee.html` also has an `employee.js`. In NetBeans, I've bound ctrl + shift + r to find and open files, so whenever I type in `employee`, both the partial and the js pop up.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason not to have script tags in the middle of your content (at least without the async and defer attributes -- not supported on every browser) is that they may block rendering of everything that's after them. There is no way the browser can predict there won't be a `document.write` in there that outputs HTML to the document. Therefore, it *must* download the script first and execute it before continuing to parse and render the rest of the site. An optimised browser might optimistically go ahead and do it anyway, then backtrack in case the script did indeed cause the output to change. Some do this and the impact is far less on those browsers.

Having a script tag in your content with an external src is not recommended mostly for those performance reasons. This does not apply to inline JavaScript, such as setting some variables or installing an event handler on generated content. It may not be pretty, but is far less of a performance penalty. You could also use those to load an external script later on. This is how Google Analytics loads it bigger tracking script, for example.